# Inconsistency in removing userDefined objects of two ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having two array list of user-defined objects.I want to remove the common elements in both.If i try to do so i am getting inconsistent results..That is the number of items that has been removed from both the arrayList are different...Below is the template of code i used..can any one help me..?

`

```
 ArrayList<UserObject> userList1=new ArrayList<UserObject>();
 ArrayList<UserObject> userList2=new ArrayList<UserObject>();
 //code to initialse values into both userList
 ArrayList<UserObject> copyOfUserList1=new ArrayList<UserObject>(userList1);
 userList1.removeAll(userList2);
 userList2.removeAll(copyOfUserList1);
```

`

Comment: Could you provide code for UserObject? Have you overriden equals method?

Comment: ya i have overridden equals method...the UserObject has many other user-defined Objects all have equal methods over ridden..

Comment: What do you mean by inconsistent results ? according to your code it's normal to have different number of items removed from each list as this number depends on the items on the other list.

Comment: if 'x' items are common to both the same 'x' items should be removed from both right..?@Sameer

Comment: Do you allow duplicate objects in your lists? I.e., if one list is (x,y,x) and the other list is (x,y,z), removing 'x' from both lists will not remove the same number of objects for both.

Comment: Can you tell more about UserObject and give the "Incostintent result that you are getting".

Comment: Actually am using JAXB to unmarshal my xml file and store it in java objects.There are nearly some 12 userdefined objects..Each have equals method overridden in it..and inconsistent result means the number of items beigng removed from both the list varies..@DushyantGupta

Comment: No duplicates are'nt allowed ..@Hanno Binder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue; I Have overridden equals method and the problem was I have used contains inside the equals method which produced the inconsistent result when the calling and the called object changes.

Answer (score 0):

it is working...

```
    ArrayList<String> userList1=new ArrayList<String>();
    userList1.add("1");
    userList1.add("7");
    userList1.add("9");
    userList1.add("4");

    ArrayList<String> userList2=new ArrayList<String>();
    userList2.add("1");
    userList2.add("5");
    userList2.add("3");
    userList2.add("4");

    ArrayList<String> copyOfUserList1=new ArrayList<String>(userList1);
    userList1.removeAll(userList2);
    userList2.removeAll(copyOfUserList1);

    System.out.println(userList1);
    System.out.println(userList2);


    output:
                [7, 9]
                [5, 3]
```

Comment: Iam storing user defined objects in the array list..@aashish_soni